# Update and/or alter localStorage database from an external sqlite query

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova

I have a few questions regarding localStorage.

1.

When I tried to update the localStorage database (in iOS WebView) from my Cordova app I noticed some strange behavior.

When I open up the database in an external DB Browser I can see the updates, but they are not visible in Safari's Web inspector. And the first JS call to LocalStorage after the update deletes all the changes and restores it to the state before the external call, kind of like it was cached in memory ?

Any ideas ? Is there a way to force the browser to reload from disk ?

2.

I have written a Cordova plugin that connects to an sqlite database and can add, update,remove etc. items in a localStorage "replica" key-value based database.

However I would like to be able to prototype Storage with like localStorage.getValue('foo'); 
I just can't get it to work... I understand the concept of asynchronous calls etc. but there must be a way.

So far I have tried loops and timeouts. -> results in browser freeze.

Is it possible to do a "one-liner" according to my specs to retrieve a db value without a callback ?

Answer (score 0):

Item 1:
Sorry, just not sure.

Item 2:

There maybe better ways of doing this, but if I were doing it and bent on not wanting to deal directly with the callbacks I would use the async.js library available at: https://github.com/caolan/async

And do something like:

```
function getValue() {
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        db.readTransaction(function (t) {
            t.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM table', [], function (t, r) {
              callback(r.rows[0].c);
            }, function (t, e) {
              console.log(e.message);
            });
          }); 
    }
],
function(error, results) {
    return results[0];
}
);
}
```

From the documentation:

> [async.series will] Run an array of functions in series, each one running once the
>   previous function has completed. If any functions in the series pass
>   an error to its callback, no more functions are run and the callback
>   for the series is immediately called with the value of the error. Once
>   the tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final callback
>   as an array.